# Meteor: getting the HTML element which is using a global helper

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Is it possible to know the HTML element which is invoking a global helper?

I have this blaze template:

```html
<template name="tools">
  <div>
    <a id="pencil" class="{{toolIsActive}}">Pencil</a>
    <a id="shape" class="{{toolIsActive}}">Shape</a>
    <a id="poly" class="{{toolIsActive}}">Polygon</a>
    <a id="arrow" class="{{toolIsActive}}">Arrow</a>
  </div>    
</template>
```

and so it'd be useful a helper like this:

```js
UI.registerHelper('toolIsActive', function() {
    return (this.id === currentTool) ? 'active' : '';
});
```

where I want `this` to be the invoking HTML element instead of template's data context.

Is there a way to access the element? I know I could use `this.$('#pencil')` but it's useless since the `id` it's exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around this problem by passing the tool name as an argument for the helper:

```
<a id="pencil" class="{{toolIsActive 'pencil'}}">Pencil</a>

UI.registerHelper('toolIsActive', function(tool) {
  return (tool === currentTool) ? 'active' : '';
});
```

---

Since this sort of helper is useful in many different parts of the application, you can make an universal one instead:

```
<a id="pencil" class="{{classIfEqual 'pencil' currentTool 'active'}}">Pencil</a>

UI.registerHelper('classIfEqual', function(a, b, className) {
  return (a === b) ? className : '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, which could make it easier to add more tools in the future:

```html
<template name="tools">
  <div>
    {{#each tools}}
      <a id="{{id}}" class="{{toolIsActive}}">{{humanName}}</a>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.tools.helpers({
  tools: [
    {id: "pencil", humanName: "Pencil"},
    {id: "shape",  humanName: "Shape"},
    {id: "poly",   humanName: "Polygon"},
    {id: "arrow",  humanName: "Arrow"}
  ],
  toolIsActive: function() {
    return (this.id === currentTool) ? "active" : ""
  }
});
```

You could potentially use that `tools` structure in multiple places, and then if you want to add more tools, you only have to add it in one place.

Comment: Even if I ended up using your solution (seems more flexible and less redundant to me), I checked @Hubert reply as accepted since it seems a better fit to my specific question (although not exactly what i was asking for). Thanks both a lot. :-)